# Import error in importing the script in another directory

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

In the following directory structure, I would like to run the code in dir_b, python run.py.

```
dir_a
 |- func_f.py
 |- func_g.py

dir_b
 |- run.py
```

The script of func_f.py is:

```
def f(x):
    return x**2
```

The script of func_g.py is:

```
from func_f import f

def g(x):
    return f(x) + 2
```

The script of run.py is:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
from dir_a import func_g

y = func_g.g(3)
print(y)
```

In the directory of dir_b, I run "python run.py"; however, the error occurred as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 3, in <module>
    from dir_a import func_g
  File "../dir_a/func_g.py", line 1, in <module>
    from func_f import f
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'func_f'
```

I write "from dir_a import func_g" but why did this error occur?   How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make `func_g.py` be:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from func_f import f
else:
    import sys
    sys.path.append('../')
    from func_f import f

def g(x):
    return f(x) + 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but the error is the same.

Comment: @neco Edited my answer

Comment: uhh... the error is the same yet...

Comment: @neco Edited my answer.

Comment: @neco Sorry was off a bit, now it should work